# How to properly calculate off-diagonal terms in covariance matrix for entangled Gaussian state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I would like to ask how to properly calculate the off-diagonal terms in covariance matrix for the entangled Gaussian state?

E.g. from https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.0534v1 we have a coherent Gaussian state in the following form
$$
|\psi\rangle = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sqrt{\frac{N^n}{(N+1)^{n+1}}}|n\rangle_A|n\rangle_B
$$
and the covariance matrix
$$
V=\frac{1}{4}
\left(
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    S & 0 & C & 0 \\
    0 & S & 0 &-C \\
    C & 0 & S & 0 \\
    0 &-C & 0 & S \\
  \end{array}
\right)
$$
where $S=2N+1$ and $C=2\sqrt{N(N+1)}$.

Using the definition of the covariance matrix
$$
V_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}Tr[\hat \rho\{\hat q_i;\hat q_j\}]
$$
(assuming zero displacement)
where $\hat \rho$ is the appropriate density operator and vector $\hat q=(\hat X_A, \hat P_A, \hat X_B, \hat P_B)$ can be expressed using kvadrature, i.e. $\hat X = \hat a + \hat a^\dagger$, $\hat P = \hat a^\dagger - \hat a$.
It is clear to me how I get the diagonal terms, but not the off-diagonal.

For example
$$
V_{13}=\frac{1}{2}Tr[\hat \rho(\hat X_A\hat X_B + \hat X_B\hat X_A ) ]
$$
since operators $A$ and $B$ commute
$$
V_{13}=Tr[\hat \rho(\hat X_A\hat X_B ) ]\\
=Tr[\hat \rho(\hat a_A + \hat a_A^\dagger )(\hat a_B + \hat a_B^\dagger ) ]
$$
but this combination of creation and annihilation operators change the states but never "return" and, therefore, trace will be zero.

Probably I do something trivially wrong, but I'm blind. Thanks.

---

**Edit 1:** in more details:
My density matrix reads
$$
\hat \rho = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{N^n}{(N+1)^{n+1}}
|n\rangle_A\langle n|
|n\rangle_B \langle n|
$$
Then the above described term 13 of the covariance matrix is
$$
V_{13}=Tr\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{N^n}{(N+1)^{n+1}}
_B\langle n|_A\langle n|
\hat a_A\hat a_B + \hat a_A^\dagger \hat a_B^\dagger + \hat a_A^\dagger\hat a_B + \hat a_A^\dagger\hat a_B
|n\rangle_A|n\rangle_B
\right]\\
Tr\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{N^n}{(N+1)^{n+1}}
_B\langle n|_A\langle n| \left(
n|n-1\rangle_A|n-1\rangle_B + (n+1)|n+1\rangle_A|n+1\rangle_B + \sqrt{n(n+1)}|n+1\rangle_A|n-1\rangle_B + \sqrt{n(n+1)}|n-1\rangle_A|n+1\rangle_B
\right)
\right]
$$
then the trace gives zero. Where I do a mistake? What is wrong?

Comment: Your state is a superposition of states with all particle numbers.  Why would you get zero? (E.g., you could remove one A and one B particle.)

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I still do not see it. I will write it in more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take two independent summation indices for the ket and the bra vector in the density matrix (and thus in the computation of expectation values).